DBEAVER Table not found
The table in question exists and my query works fine, I can see the data.
But there is a red line under the table name, when I hover it says "Table XYZ not found".
I tried looking for the checkbox of "Show all databases" in my connection. I can't seem to find it.

Post the select here to help us. Did you use schema before table_name?
Example: select * from SCHEMANAME.TABLE_NAME;
?
